# 500 error while doing a put/post/patch request in react native ios

Tags: ios, node.js, react-native, express, axios

I am attempting to create a put request to my react native (0.60.4) ios project and every time I do so I receive a 500 error when making my request. I am getting the same error while doing a post or patch method as well. I also receive a 500 error while attempting to make the request with postman.

My sql update works fine as I have ran the script against the database and received the expected value, which is simply updating a boolean value.

Here is my update method in redux

```
export const setChecklistItemToComplete = checklistItemId => {
  var checklistItemInstance = axios({
    method: 'put',
    url: `http://localhost:8080/xxxxxxxx/${checklistItemId}`,
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json;charset=UTF-8',
      'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'
    }
  })
  console.log('checklistItemInstance: ', checklistItemInstance)
  return {
    type: MARK_CHECKLIST_ITEM_COMPLETE,
    payload: checklistItemInstance.data
  }
}
```

Here is my controller

```
  try {
    const db = req.app.get('db')
    const { MarkChecklistItemComplete } = db.checklistItem.put
    const { params = {} } = req
    const { checklistItemId } = params

    console.log('checklistItemId: ', checklistItemId) <---GETS TO HERE
    if (joi.string().guid(checklistItemId)) {
      throw new Error('The id is not in the correct format')
    }

    var checklistItemInstance = await MarkChecklistItemComplete({
      checklistItemId
    })

    res.status(200)
    res.json(checklistItemInstance)
  } catch (error) {
    res.status(500)
    res.json(error)
  }
}
```

I'm assuming this has nothing to do with this code here but more so the configuration of the app itself. But it can't hurt to post it. If there is anything else you would like to see I will gladly share that.

Comment: You don't send any data in your axios put

Comment: Also first, be sure your api works with postman, then try to integrate into react-native

Comment: First http 500 means your backend could not response to your request. You are not sending any body while using put but its not frontend concern. It has to handled in backend. In my opinion you have to check fields in backend end throw ... is required

Comment: @Neo There doesn't need to be a body because it is just toggling a boolean value in the SQL itself, but it is still an update. I do have a check for the Id coming through in the controller that throws an error if the value is out of the format for a guid/uuid, which it isn', hence why it gets to the call to the script, but that's where it fails. I have read somewhere that developing with React Native and ios requires the use of https which is why I mentioned configuration of the app.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong with `react-native` request because you get an error inside your `try catch` block of code, so request itself is fine. As you said, you're getting the same error via Postman.

From what I see you use PUT request, but you don't use any body. Also your code does not reach `res.status(200)` line, but reaches this one `console.log('checklistItemId: ', checklistItemId)`. So the error is definitely in call of `MarkChecklistItemComplete({ checklistItemId })` function. So either `checklistItemId` has some wrong/unexpected value or function `MarkChecklistItemComplete` contains an error inside.

Comment: So `MarkChecklistItemComplete` is sql, as I said I have tested running that and that works as expected with togging the boolean value to true. It is a put because it is doing an update to the database but there is no body because a body is unnecessary to toggle a value to true.

Answer (score 0):

Well this is what happens when you went on a 10 hour coding spree...

My if statement in the controller was checking the checklistId value and throwing an error if the id was in the correct format. I did not invert the value of the check...

```
if (joi.string().guid(checklistItemId)) {
      throw new Error('The id is not in the correct format')
    }
```

goes to

```
   if (!joi.string().guid(checklistItemId)) {
      throw new Error('The id is not in the correct format')
    }
```

Comment: Probably you want to mark this answer as 'right' then, or just delete your question as unnecessary for the community:) It's a bit confusing because of `react-native` in question's title.

Comment: Can't delete it and can't mark it right until tomorrow :( @E.Dn